# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "Gier" und "Habgier"

Tags: difference

Mir ist diese Frage in den Sinn gekommen, als überall in den Medien stand, der Anschlag auf den BVB-Bus wurde aus **Habgier** begangen. Interessanterweise war der Täter aber an der Börse aktiv, wo ein wiederkehrendes Motiv für Handlungen aller Art **Gier** ist.

Abgesehen von diesem konkreten Beispiel: Wo ist im Allgemeinen der Unterschied zwischen den Begriffen "Gier" und "Habgier"? Wird "Habgier" lediglich verwendet, um die "Schlechtigkeit" nochmals hervorzuheben, oder gibt es einen inhaltlichen Unterschied? Mir fällt nämlich als Muttersprachler keiner ein.

Comment: Man kann ohne weiteres einen ganzen Schweinebraten *aus Gier* verspeisen (so man es denn verträgt) - Aber sicher nicht *aus Habgier*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Habgier** ist das starke Verlangen, den eigenen Besitz zu vermehren, während sich (der Oberbegriff) **Gier** auch auf anderes beziehen kann.

Gier nach

> - Liebe
> - Anerkennung
> - Aufmerksamkeit
> - (...)

Comment: Hinzu kommt, dass [Habgier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habgier#Strafrecht) eine juristische Bedeutung als Mordmerkmal hat.

Answer (score 1):

Gier ist das übersteigerte Bedürfnis nach etwas, etwa die Gier nach Essen.  Habgier ist das übersteigerte Bedürfnis nach der Anhäufung (und nicht etwa dem Erwerb) von Besitz.  Jemand, der spielsüchtig ist, ist typischerweise von Gier getrieben aber nicht von Habgier, weil die Mehrung des festen Besitzes eben nicht eine mit einiger Wahrscheinlichkeit absehbare Folge des Spieles ist.

"Habsucht", "Habgier", "Raffsucht", "Raffgier" sind ziemlich exakte Synonyme, so daß "raffen" hier ebenfalls ein in erster Linie erfolgreiches Handeln impliziert.